# Need a little help understanding this AsyncTask scenario

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I need some clarity understanding how AsyncTask processing will happen in my scenario. I have a plain java object called **Donor**.

There is an activity (say **DonorDetailActivity**) which modifies this donor object. The modification takes place in an **AsyncTask<>** (say **DonorEditService**). So from **DonorDetailActivity**, **DonorEditService** is invoked which edits **Donor** in background thread, and publishes the result to the main UI thread.

**DonorDetailActivity class**

```
public class DonorDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AsyncTaskCallback<Donor>{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        btnEditDonor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { //Invoke the DonorEditService
                    DonorEditService editService = new DonorEditService(DonorDetailActivity.this);
                    editService.execute(donor);
            }
        });
    }

    //Invoked from DonorEditService.onPostExecute(DonorBase updatedDonor)
    @Override
    public void onAsyncTaskCompleted(Donor updatedDonor) {
        updateUI(); //Refresh screen with updatedDonor
    }
}
```

All this updating Donor code works correctly. Now I have a situation where user can make a phone call to donor. In that process, I have to update a field of Donor to reflect Last Called Date. For that I can see two ways. First update the Donor in background thread and then start a Phone Call Intent, or first start Phone Call intent and then update the Donor. Code wise something like below

**First Update and then Call**

```
//Update Donor
DonorEditService editService = new DonorEditService(activity);
donor.setLastCallDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
editService.execute(donor);
//
Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + prefix + donor.getMobileNumber()));
activity.startActivity(phoneIntent);
```

**First Call and then Update**

```
Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + prefix + donor.getMobileNumber()));
activity.startActivity(phoneIntent);
//Update Donor
DonorEditService editService = new DonorEditService(activity);
donor.setLastCallDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
editService.execute(donor);
//
```

Fortunately or unfortunately both these are working on the emulator. The only concern is that how **AsyncTask.onPostExecute()** is invoked in case the calling activity is not in **OnResume** status. That is it is blocked by the **Phone Call Activity**. Also, which approach is better; Edit first and Call; or Call first and the Edit

**EDIT:**

I just realized from @Darwind's comment that I should have shown the code for the **DonorEditService**, which is actually `AsyncTask<DonorBase>` (and not an android [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)). DonorBase is super class of Donor.

Here is some part of the **DonoEditService** code

```
public class DonorEditService extends AsyncTask<DonorBase, Void, DonorBase> {
    public DonorEditService(Activity activity, boolean displayProgressDialog) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Show Progress Dialog for Donor Edit process
    }

    @Override
    protected DonorBase doInBackground(DonorBase... donors) {
        //Carry out the Http request to Edit Donor on Server
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DonorBase updatedDonor) {
        //Run on Main UI thread. I invoke AsyncTaskCallback from here
        taskCallback.onAsyncTaskCompleted(updatedDonor); //taskCallback is DonorDetailActivity implementing AsyncCallback
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `DonorEditService` using the activity for? To me it looks like you're leaking the activity, by passing the reference to your service, so when the user navigates away from the activity by making a phone call, Android tries to pause the activity, but can't because the activity is still referenced by the service. This is probably why it works for both your ways, but it's clearly not the correct solution. Activities shouldn't bind to services like you're doing it.

Comment: I just read your question again. I didn't understand at first, that you've named your `AsycnTask` for `Service`. But basically what I wrote above still holds - you shouldn't keep a reference to your `Activity` in your `AsyncTask`. If you do, you'll "leak" the reference when the user is leaving the `Activity` when making a phonecall. Now when the user comes back from the phonecall, the `Activity` is possibly resumed, but it could be a whole new instance of the `Activity` and so you've leaked the first instance of the `Activity`. It's still there, but can't be reached so now you have 2 instances

Comment: @Darwind you assumed correct that I am using AsyncTask<Donor> (see the edited question). Actually, I invoke the AsyncTask from Detail Activity and I was expecting that the Activity should be notified when the AsyncTask completes, so that I could update the UI shown by the Detail Activity. The problem of notifying the Detail Activity occurs because the AsyncTask(DonorEditService) is coded in a separate java file and not as a nested class of Detail Activity. This is because the AsyncTask is called from multiple places. What can be workaround to passing the Detail Activity and causing the leak?

Comment: I added an answer - these comment fields are so small ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are many solutions to your problem.

First of all I'd suggest you to not pass in the `DetailActivity` as a parameter to the `AsyncTask`, as this will lead to the leak.

At first I thought it would be a good idea using a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for your purpose, but figured out, that this would not work, since you leave the `DetailActivity` and go for a phone call and probably wouldn't get the broadcast in the end.

Instead I suggest you to implement a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), because your `Activity` can `bind` and `unbind` to the `Service` and ask for informations about the `Service`. The idea is that your `Service` will run even though the user navigates away from your `DetailActivity` and so can keep some data until the user comes back to your app.

Then when the user comes back to your app and resumes the `DetailActivity` you just need to "bind" to the `Service` again and request to see if there's something that was changed while the user was away.

You can keep your `AsyncTask` and instead of letting the `DetailActivity` call it directly, make the `Service` call it directly, so the `DetailActivity` call the `Service` and this will call through to the `AsyncTask`.

Now I see you've implemented an `Observer pattern` for the `DetailActivity` to be notified whenever the `AsyncTask` is done. Instead of this "hardly coupled" Observer pattern I would actually suggest that you implemented the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), so the `AsyncTask` would send "broadcasts" to the `DetailActivity`. Now when the `DetailActivity` is paused (user is making a phone call), the broadcast won't be picked up by the `DetailActivity`, but that's fine. The broadcasts should only be picked up when the user has your app in 100% focus (visible).

Sorry for the wall of text, but this is somewhat of an "advanced" subject. I hope it helps you, if not, I'll try to extend with some code :-)

Comment: I tried to read a little about the "Service", and would give a thought. Actually, I also see another option of cancelling the AsyncTask itself when the calling Activity is about to be Destroyed(in OnDestroy() Activity callback). Basically, store a reference of AsyncTask(DonorEditService) that is being invoked (say as mAsyncTask variable), in the Detail Activity. Then in that Detail Activity override OnDestroy() callback to cancel the AsyncTask if its still running, something like mAsyncTask.cancel(true). Thanks for your valuable inputs, but I keep this thread active till tomorrow.

Comment: Sure that's also a solution - but I wasn't under the impression that you didn't care for the `AsyncTask` to finish? If you cancel the `AsyncTask` before it finishes you won't be able to call `updateUI()` because the data you were handling in the `AsyncTask` wasn't necessarily updated/changed. The `Service` may seem like a complex subject, but I think it's what you need :-)